# MySql's Connector/Net with MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to get some information regarding using MySQL alongside ASP.NET (particularly MVC 3). From what I've found and experienced, it doesn't quite seem as customizable in terms of the Membership and User classes which come with Asp.Net, especially when it comes to validation or registration.

For example, after configuring my web.config file to use MySQL, I found myself realizing that, although a fair amount of tables were auto-generated for me to use, I wasn't able to change the names of them. Because of this, it seemed as though if I were to change a column name, or add a column to the table, it wouldn't quite work with the system, since everything has been pre-built.

Yet, with ADO.Net/Entity Framework, it appears that I might actually be able to have more freedom in how I go about creating my websites using MsSQL. Is this true? Is MySQL just not meant for ASP.Net, despite the the fact that you can install and use it at your leisure. Or is it that it just requires more work to get everything working, and you kind of have to reinvent the wheel by creating your own database classes and validation tools?

I'm not trying to bash either MySql or MsSql, I'm simply looking for a good analysis on the topic, as Google hasn't helped me much in this area.

Comment: To be brutally honest, the default "providers" (membership/auth etc) with ASP.Net MVC are utter turds.  Write your own providers with EF or NHibernate as a back end and all will be well.  You can choose your own schema as well then.  For ref, there is nothing whatsoever wrong with any database in particular for this task.

Comment: Ah, very coolness. Thank you. One question though, what is EF stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more an issue with the default providers, and one of the many reasons why the 1st thing I did when I learnt about them was to try and make my own. (To be clear, creating your own one from scratch does require a fair amount of work, there are a few good tutorials out there that can give you a quick start)

[It'd make all our lives easier if the .Net framework used Interfaces for the providers rather than the base class... ]

To be clear, the big thing with the auto generated providers is the sprocs they use require the specified names, if you want to change the table names then you'll have to also update all the Sprocs as well. (This is true for any custom provider you may chose to build/use)